# Транзакции в MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, transaction

Имеется коллекция в `MongoDB` в которой хранятся данные об обработке данных `expressjs` сервером .

Так как обработка происходит асинхронно, а целостность этих данных очень важна я пришел к использованию транзакций. Драйвером `MongoDB` в моем случае выступает `mongoose`. Код примерно таков (он упрощен и не имеет некоторых валидаций):

```js
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const app = express();
const Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    id: Number,
    name: String
}, {
    autoCreate: true
});
const Data = mongoose.model('Data', Schema );
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    if(req.query.id && req.query.name) {
        //Начало сессии
        const session = await Data.startSession();
        //Запуск транзакции
        session.startTransaction();
        try {
            //Поиск уже существующей записи
            const exits = await Data.findOne({id: req.query.id, name: req.query.name}).session(session);
            
            if (exits === null) {//Если ее нет, то создаем
                await Data({id: req.query.id, name: req.query.name}).save({session});
            }
            await session.commitTransaction();
        } catch (error) {
            await session.abortTransaction();
            session.endSession();
            console.log(error)
        } finally {
            session.endSession();
        }
    }
    res.send('ok')
})

app.listen(3000)
```

Гарантирует ли такой подход исключение ситуации с асинхронным выполнением двух транзакций когда поступает 2 одинаковых запроса и когда (как это было бы при операциях без транзакции):

1. **Запрос #1** Делает запрос на проверку существования | **Запрос #2**  уже ранее сделал запрос, но не сделал insert
2. **Запрос #1** Проверил на существование и понял что записи еще нет | **Запрос #2**  Все еще не сделал insert
3. **Запрос #1** Делает insert  | **Запрос #2**  Делает insert
4. В базе имеется 2 экземпляра одной записи

Если подход с транзакциями это исключит, тогда вопрос. Транзакции выполняются по очереди и до завершения активной транзакции коллекция не может быть модифицирована из вне?

Если одна транзакция выполнится, получается что вторая так же выполнится успешно проверив на существование, и так как запись будет уже добавлена первой транзакцией, то просто не добавит новую?

Обязательно ли делать `session.commitTransaction();` если я не делал изменений в базе и только делал из нее выборки (случай когда `exits !== null`)

Comment: сделай уникальный индекс (unique index) и не заморачивайся

Comment: проблема в том что `id` уникален только для конкретного name, но не для всей коллекции

Comment: Транзакциями этого не решить, транзакция нужна для других целей. Ищите в сторону блокировки таблицы, записей.

Comment: уникальный индекс по двум полям

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko разве транзакции не гарантируют атомарность и выполнение как как будто они выполняются по очереди? А в чем тогда их смысл кроме rollback'a

Comment: @nörbörnën в таком случае, я так понимаю я смогу в коллекцию создать только один документ с одним именем, и только один документ с определённым Id. Мне требуется чтобы я мог создать неограниченое количество документов с одним именем, но уникальным id для конкретного имени

Comment: нужно создать уникальный индекс для пары `id, name` https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/#unique-compound-index

Comment: действительно , вроде работает `Schema.index({"id" : 1, "name" : 1}, {"unique" : true})`, а что по поводу транзакций, я вроде читал, они должны гарантировать целостность. Я впервые использую транзакции, и думал это решит мою проблему, «транзакция это нескольких запросов, которые трактуются как единый запрос» разве нет?

Comment: в твоей задаче нет места в транзакции, достаточно будет индекса и выполнения `try { await Data({id: req.query.id, name: req.query.name}).save() } catch(err){}`. этот save вполне атомарен на нашем уровне

Comment: У вас же проблема не в атомарности, а в [concurrency](https://www.google.com/search?q=concurrency&rlz=1C1GGRV_enUZ780UZ780&oq=concurrency&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3j46l2j0j46j0l2.592j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) - в параллельном выполнении кода.

Comment: @nörbörnën в в noSQL(в данном случае mongodb) есть возможность блокировки схемы\записей? Ни разу просто с ними в продакшене серьезном не работал.

Comment: @viiprogrammer https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/concurrency/#does-mongodb-support-transactions- Because a single document can contain related data that would otherwise be modeled across separate parent-child tables in a relational schema, MongoDB's atomic single-document operations already provide transaction semantics that meet the data integrity needs of the majority of applications .... The guarantees provided by MongoDB ensure complete isolation as a document is updated; any errors cause the operation to roll back so that clients receive a consistent view of the document.